# How to determine stack size in LLVM IR

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, riscv

Is there any way to determine the stack size in LLVM IR. I need to determine the stack size assuming all static variables are present on the stack. I am using `riscv-llvm` version 5.0. I have also looked up `MachineFrameInfo.h` which has a method named `getStackSize()`, but as far as I have found out it seems to work after the prolog and epilog code inserter has finalized the stack frame layout. Moreover, it seems to work after the IR level. So is there any way to determine the stack size in LLVM IR

Comment: The easy, but not entirely accurate way, is to scan for [alloca](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1AllocaInst.html) in a function pass, look at how much each of them allocates, and add that up. However, the code generator is free to push a little more on to the stack to implement register spills. You'll also need to think about what to do if alloca [is called in a loop](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopAnalysis.html).

Comment: I thought of this as well but backed off due to code generator pushing some more space on the stack. Alloca's get assigned at the top of the function call, so not worried about variable declaration in loops.

Comment: It is only true for IR produced by Clang. Nothing prevents arbitrary pass or another compiler from inserting `alloca`s into a middle of the function.

Comment: @SouravDas: Just for reading, this is an old question also on llvm-dev. See: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2013-September/065333.html

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704212/what-purpose-does-elfs-stack-size-metadata-have - it may help.

Comment: I'm trying to answer this question for myself. I think this is of interest blog.japaric.io/stack-analysis. It mostly concentrates on rustc but it does get around to clang eventually.

Comment: @AndyPreston Thanks This is a nice pointer.